# CompletableFuture : Invoke a void function asynchronusly

Tags: java, runnable, callable, completable-future

I am trying to implement a database query with retry strategy on certain database exceptions. The code for retry strategy is not very relevant, so I did not include it. As you can see in the code below - I have written a retryCallable which takes the retry strategy and the Callable in `populateData()`.

In `getDataFromDB`, I get the data from DB and put the data in a global hashmap which serves as a cache at an application level.

This code is working as expected. I would like to invoke `populateData` from a different class. However, this would be a blocking call. Since this is Database and has retry strategy, this could be slow. I want to call `populateData` asynchronously.

How can I use CompletableFuture or FutureTask to achieve this? 
`CompletableFuture.runAsync` expects a runnable. `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` expects a supplier. I have not implemented these things before. So any advice on best practices would be helpful.

```
Class TestCallableRetry {

public void populateData() {
        final Callable<Set<String>> retryCallable = new RetryingCallable<>(retryStrategyToRetryOnDBException(), getDataFromDB());
        Set<String> data = new HashSet<>();

        data = retryCallable.call();

        if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
            // store data in a global hash map
        }
    }

    private Callable<Set<Building>> getDataFromDB() {
        return new Callable<Set<String>>() {
            @Override
            public Set<String> call() {
                // returns data from database
            }
        };
    }
}

Class InvokeCallableAsynchronously {
    public void putDataInGlobalMap {
      // call populateData asynchronously
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you split your `populateData` method into two parts, one `Supplier` to fetch the data and another `Consumer` to store it, it will be easy to chain them with a `CompletableFuture`.

```
// Signature compatible with Supplier<Set<String>> 
private Set<String> fetchDataWithRetry() {
    final RetryingCallable<Set<String>> retryCallable = new RetryingCallable<>(retryStrategyToRetryOnDBException(), getDataFromDB());
    try {
        return retryCallable.call();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Call to database failed", e);
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
}

// Signature compatible with Consumer<Set<String>>
private void storeData(Set<String> data) {
    if (!data.isEmpty()) {
        // store data in a global hash map
    }
}
```

Then, in `populateData()`:

```
private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

public void populateData() {
    CompletableFuture
        .supplyAsync(this::fetchDataWithRetry, executor)
        .thenAccept(this::storeData);
}
```

The use of the version of `supplyAsync` that takes an `Executor` is optional. If you use the single arg version your task will run in the common pool; OK for short running tasks but not for tasks that block.

Comment: nice and simpler one, as I have changed the `getDataFromDB()` signature

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I will give this a try.

Answer (score 2):

There are various utility methods you combine within a `CompletableFuture` and it's really worth exploring all of them.

Let's start with the `populateData` method. By its name you can deduce it should accept a data stream from somewhere.

Its signature could then look like this:

```
void populateData ( Supplier<? extends Collection<Building> dataSupplier );
```

`Supplier`, as the name suggests, it simply something that provides us with some data.

`getDataFromDB()` seems to be suitable as a `Supplier` role.

```
private Set<Building> getDataFromDB() // supply a building's collection
```

We want `populateData` to execute `asynchronously` and return a result whether the operation was performed correctly or not.

So, in the future, `populateData` may return, and tell us how things went.

Let's transform the signature into:

```
CompletableFuture<Result> populateData(Supplier<? extends Collection<Building>> supplier);
```

Now let's see how the method body may look like:

```
CompletableFuture<Result> populateData(Supplier<? extends Collection<Building>> supplier) {
    return CompletableFuture                // create new completable future from factory method
            .supplyAsync(supplier)          // execute the supplier method (getDataFromDB() in our case) 
            .thenApplyAsync(data -> {       // here we can work on the data supplied
                if (data == null || data.isEmpty()) return new Result(false);
                // some heavy operations
                for (Building building : data) {
                    // do something
                }

                return new Result(true); // return dummy positive result data            
             })
             .handleAsync((result, throwable) -> {
                // check if there was any exception
                if (throwable != null) {
                    // check if exception was thrown
                    Log.log(throwable);
                    return new Result(false);
                }
                return result;
            });
}
```

Now we can call `populateData` from somewhere, and apply another callback to execute when it has finished executing asynchronously.

```
populateData(TestCallableRetry::getDataFromDB).thenAccept( result -> {
        if ( ! result.success ) {
            // things went bad... retry ??
        }
    });
```

Now it depends how you want to apply your **retry strategy**. If you just care to re-try once, you can just call `populateData` a second time within `thenAcceptAsync`.

You should also `catch` exceptions within your supplier method and convert them into a `java.util.concurrent.CompletionException` as they are handled smoothly within a `CompletableFuture`.

Answer (score 0):

its very simple since java8 simply use
`CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> object.func());`

Comment: This was probably flagged automatically because of its length. Short answers like this often don't provide enough context to really be useful. In this case, a description of *how* to use the proposed solution would be a big improvement.

Comment: Hey, please help me understand why this is not answering the question and what do you mean by how to use the proposed solution? should i just add that 'if object is  the instance of `TestCallableRetry` the user can invoke -  `CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> object.populateData());`'